# How to understand the "isCommitted" property of ParserResult?

Tags: parsing, dart

I'm reading the source of polux's great [parsers](https://github.com/polux/parsers), and found there is a special `isCommitted` property which I can't understand:

```dart
class ParseResult<A> {
  final bool isSuccess;
  final bool isCommitted;
  /// [:null:] if [:!isSuccess:]
  final A value;
  final String text;
  final Position position;
  final Expectations expectations;
  // ...
}
```

You can see there is already a `isSuccess` to indicate the parse result is successful or not, why do we need a `isCommitted`? I tried to read related code, but still don't understand.

If you want to see the source, you can find it [here](https://github.com/polux/parsers/blob/master/lib/parsers.dart#L85).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: don't worry about `isCommited`, it's for internal purposes only.

The long answer is: you can call `commited` on a paser, which means that once it has succeeded, you know for sure that it's pointless to backtrack (very much like Prolog's cut). For instance consider a grammar like this:

```
expr() => str('(') + rec(expr) str(')') ^ ...
        | num()
```

Assume we parse the string `"(..."`. Once we have recognized the parenthesis, we know for sure that if `...` turns out **not** to be an expr, there is no need to rewind to the start of the string and try to parse a num, since a num will never start with a parenthesis anyway. We can fail early. This is done by marking `(` as being a "commit point":

```
expr() => str('(').commited + rec(expr) str(')') ^ ...
        | num()
```

This is an optimisation which should be used with great care because it breaks the modularity of parsers with respect to `|`. I personally never had to use it so far.

Whenever you call `commited` on a parser, it returns a new parser whose `isCommited` property is true. It is then used by `|` to decide whether to backtrack or not. This is what `isCommited` is used for. As an end user you should never have to care. I should probably make it private.

This feature is inspired by [Polyparse's commit](http://code.haskell.org/~malcolm/polyparse/docs/).